# jQuery open element only for current parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kxgh1L9o/). The only thing I need is that when I click to ReadMore it will show only its parents map and not map from the others. How can I achieve that? I tried it with .each() function

```
$('article').each(function(i){
    $(this).find('a').click(function(){
         $('.map').toggle();
    });
});
```

but I can't still find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need each loop.You can perform this task just click event.

```
$('.readmore').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('article').find('.map').toggle();
});
```

here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dipakparmar/L6zdqay3/).

Answer (score 1):

Since `.map` element is inside of the parent of the clicked element you have to use `$(this).parent()` to `find()` the element you are looking for:

```
$('article').each(function(i){
  $(this).find('a').click(function(){
     $(this).parent().find('.map').toggle();
  });
});
```

But the following is enough (no need to iterate over `article`) for what you are trying achieve:

```
$('a.readmore').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.map').toggle();
});
```

```js
$('a.readmore').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.map').toggle();
});
```

```css
.map{
  display: none;
}

article{
  border: 2px solid gray;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.text{
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <content>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a ultricies eros, eu commodo nisi. Etiam malesuada augue velit, vel posuere nunc lobortis eu.   Praesent suscipit ligula id ipsum consequat aliquet. Donec efficitur magna vel fringilla ornare. Quisque sed nisi ut diam sollicitudin iaculis. Nulla dignissim   suscipit accumsan. Nulla condimentum lorem ac erat tristique, ut pharetra ligula feugiat. Phasellus non tellus elit.
    </div>
    <div class="map">
      googlemap
    </div>
  </content>
  <a class="readmore">Read More</a>
</article>

<article>
  <content>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a ultricies eros, eu commodo nisi. Etiam malesuada augue velit, vel posuere nunc lobortis eu.   Praesent suscipit ligula id ipsum consequat aliquet. Donec efficitur magna vel fringilla ornare. Quisque sed nisi ut diam sollicitudin iaculis. Nulla dignissim   suscipit accumsan. Nulla condimentum lorem ac erat tristique, ut pharetra ligula feugiat. Phasellus non tellus elit.
    </div>
    <div class="map">
      googlemap
    </div>
  </content>
  <a class="readmore">Read More</a>
</article>

<article>
  <content>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a ultricies eros, eu commodo nisi. Etiam malesuada augue velit, vel posuere nunc lobortis eu.   Praesent suscipit ligula id ipsum consequat aliquet. Donec efficitur magna vel fringilla ornare. Quisque sed nisi ut diam sollicitudin iaculis. Nulla dignissim   suscipit accumsan. Nulla condimentum lorem ac erat tristique, ut pharetra ligula feugiat. Phasellus non tellus elit.
    </div>
    <div class="map">
      googlemap
    </div>
  </content>
  <a class="readmore">Read More</a>
</article>
```

Comment: Hey, I'm still trying to make it work but still, don't have any solution. I have a jSFiddle here I don't know why my solution not working. https://jsfiddle.net/5y0fnv1g/ Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Energizer7, based on the HTML  in the fiddle your selector should be `$('#content .article1 a').click(function(){`

Comment: @Energizer7, one more thing, there is no reference of the jQuery file in the fiddle you have created........

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code a little bit. This will hide all the maps first and then show the map belong to the current click. This way there only will be only one map visible at all times.

**Update:** Fixed an issue so the map you click on is toggled and all others are hidden away.

```js
$('article').find('a').click(function(){
    var thisMap = $(this).parents('article').find('.map');
    $('article').find('.map').not(thisMap ).hide();
    thisMap.toggle();
});
```

```css
.map{
  display: none;
}

article{
  border: 2px solid gray;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.text{
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <content>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a ultricies eros, eu commodo nisi. Etiam malesuada augue velit, vel posuere nunc lobortis eu.   Praesent suscipit ligula id ipsum consequat aliquet. Donec efficitur magna vel fringilla ornare. Quisque sed nisi ut diam sollicitudin iaculis. Nulla dignissim   suscipit accumsan. Nulla condimentum lorem ac erat tristique, ut pharetra ligula feugiat. Phasellus non tellus elit.
    </div>
    <div class="map">
      googlemap
    </div>
  </content>
  <a class="readmore">Read More</a>
</article>

<article>
  <content>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a ultricies eros, eu commodo nisi. Etiam malesuada augue velit, vel posuere nunc lobortis eu.   Praesent suscipit ligula id ipsum consequat aliquet. Donec efficitur magna vel fringilla ornare. Quisque sed nisi ut diam sollicitudin iaculis. Nulla dignissim   suscipit accumsan. Nulla condimentum lorem ac erat tristique, ut pharetra ligula feugiat. Phasellus non tellus elit.
    </div>
    <div class="map">
      googlemap
    </div>
  </content>
  <a class="readmore">Read More</a>
</article>

<article>
  <content>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a ultricies eros, eu commodo nisi. Etiam malesuada augue velit, vel posuere nunc lobortis eu.   Praesent suscipit ligula id ipsum consequat aliquet. Donec efficitur magna vel fringilla ornare. Quisque sed nisi ut diam sollicitudin iaculis. Nulla dignissim   suscipit accumsan. Nulla condimentum lorem ac erat tristique, ut pharetra ligula feugiat. Phasellus non tellus elit.
    </div>
    <div class="map">
      googlemap
    </div>
  </content>
  <a class="readmore">Read More</a>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Solution

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Check the code</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('class').each(function(i){
    $(this).find('a').click(function(){
         $this('.map').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="map">Map Location</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the `.each` function. You can use this code since your `.map` element isn't inside the clicked element:

```
$('article a').click(function () {
     $(this).closest("article").find('.map').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take look at jsfiddle link and below code
jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kxgh1L9o/15/

```
$('article').each(function(i){
    $(this).find('a').click(function(){

            $(this).siblings().find(".map").toggle();
        });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Breaking this up into a click handler and event creator for clarity.
The issue you were having is one of specificity, you need to make sure to narrow the scope of your event.  Below is an example (using arrow functions for clarity over what we are accessing rather than standard function and 'this').

1. select event target
2. traverse the DOM up to the parent element (`<article />`)
3. find element within parent with class of `.map`
4. toggle found class's visibility

```js
const clickHandler =  event => {
      $(event.target)    // get event target ('this' is often used in a non arrow function)
        .parent()        // find parent of target element (article)
        .find('.map')    // find class '.map' inside parent element
        .toggle();       // toggle visibility
    }

$('article').each((index, element) => {
  $(element)
    .find('a')                  // find anchor in article
    .on('click', clickHandler); // on click trigger event
});
```

```css
.map{
  display: none;
}

article{
  border: 2px solid gray;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.text{
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <content>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a ultricies eros, eu commodo nisi. Etiam malesuada augue velit, vel posuere nunc lobortis eu.   Praesent suscipit ligula id ipsum consequat aliquet. Donec efficitur magna vel fringilla ornare. Quisque sed nisi ut diam sollicitudin iaculis. Nulla dignissim   suscipit accumsan. Nulla condimentum lorem ac erat tristique, ut pharetra ligula feugiat. Phasellus non tellus elit.
    </div>
    <div class="map">
      googlemap
    </div>
  </content>
  <a class="readmore">Read More</a>
</article>

<article>
  <content>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a ultricies eros, eu commodo nisi. Etiam malesuada augue velit, vel posuere nunc lobortis eu.   Praesent suscipit ligula id ipsum consequat aliquet. Donec efficitur magna vel fringilla ornare. Quisque sed nisi ut diam sollicitudin iaculis. Nulla dignissim   suscipit accumsan. Nulla condimentum lorem ac erat tristique, ut pharetra ligula feugiat. Phasellus non tellus elit.
    </div>
    <div class="map">
      googlemap
    </div>
  </content>
  <a class="readmore">Read More</a>
</article>

<article>
  <content>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a ultricies eros, eu commodo nisi. Etiam malesuada augue velit, vel posuere nunc lobortis eu.   Praesent suscipit ligula id ipsum consequat aliquet. Donec efficitur magna vel fringilla ornare. Quisque sed nisi ut diam sollicitudin iaculis. Nulla dignissim   suscipit accumsan. Nulla condimentum lorem ac erat tristique, ut pharetra ligula feugiat. Phasellus non tellus elit.
    </div>
    <div class="map">
      googlemap
    </div>
  </content>
  <a class="readmore">Read More</a>
</article>
```